# C++ - Merge two sorted arrays ordered in descending order

Tags: c++, arrays, sorting

I have two arrays:

Array 1:

```
e[0] = 21.145;
e[1] = 17.152;
e[2] = 15.541;
e[3] = 0.095;
e[4] = -10.515;
```

Array 2:

```
double *f = new double[5];
f[0] = 18.458;
f[1] = 11.542;
f[2] = 7.152;
f[3] = 1.243;
f[4] = -12.758;
```

I need to merge and order these arrays. Here is my code, but it's working for reverse order (as ascending). I want help with descending merge of arrays. I tried replacing operators, but it's not working. Where I mistake?

```
void mergeArrays(double * arr1, double  * arr2, int n1, int n2, double * arr3){

  int i = 0, j = 0, k = 0;

  while (i<n1 && j <n2)
  {
      if (arr1[i] < arr2[j])
          arr3[k++] = arr1[i++];
      else
          arr3[k++] = arr2[j++];
  }
  while (i < n1)
      arr3[k++] = arr1[i++];

  while (j < n2)
      arr3[k++] = arr2[j++];    
  }
```

Comment: Why doesn't `if (arr1[i] > arr2[j])` do the trick? Did you try to change all the `<` operators?

Comment: @SudheeshSinganamalla yes, im tried change all < operators for > and reverse. Its return some as -627743856220419248787898888839302069250..

Comment: The values `i` and `j` are counters for your array indices, you have to loop through them from `0-(n-1)` or `(n-1)-0`, The main condition where you are creating the 3rd array is based on which number is larger, that's just achieved by changing the `if` condition. Changing all the operators doesn't do the job here and instead will point to `arr1[-1]` for example which doesn't exist and throws garbage values as you received.

Comment: @SudheeshSinganamalla - thank you, It really was enough to change one condition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With a correct sign, the code works fine:

```
#include <iostream>

void mergeArrays(double * arr1, double  * arr2, int n1, int n2, double * arr3)
{
    int i = 0, j = 0, k = 0;

    while (i<n1 && j <n2)
    {
        if (arr1[i] > arr2[j])
            arr3[k++] = arr1[i++];
        else
            arr3[k++] = arr2[j++];
    }
    while (i < n1)
        arr3[k++] = arr1[i++];

    while (j < n2)
        arr3[k++] = arr2[j++];
}

int main()
{
    double *e = new double[5];
    e[0] = 21.145;
    e[1] = 17.152;
    e[2] = 15.541;
    e[3] = 0.095;
    e[4] = -10.515;
    double *f = new double[5];
    f[0] = 18.458;
    f[1] = 11.542;
    f[2] = 7.152;
    f[3] = 1.243;
    f[4] = -12.758;
    double *g = new double[10];
    mergeArrays(e,f,5,5,g);
    for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
        std::cout<<g[i]<<std::endl;
    delete e;
    delete f;
    delete g;

    return 0;
}
```

Result:

```
21.145
18.458
17.152
15.541
11.542
7.152
1.243
0.095
-10.515
-12.758
```